# oracle 11g long startup after shutdown abort

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I meant shutdown database with `shutdown immediate`,but it not finish after 20min.Then I use `shutdown abort` to shutdown it.
 when I start,it take 3-4 hours to change `mount` status to `open`.
 below is alter.log:

```
Startedredoapplicationat
Thread1:logseq18964,block96750
RecoveryofOnlineRedoLog:Thread1Group5Seq18964Readingmem0
Mem#0:/storage/app/oracle/oradata/sjzk/redo05.log
RecoveryofOnlineRedoLog:Thread1Group6Seq18965Readingmem0
Mem#0:/storage/app/oracle/oradata/sjzk/redo06.log
RecoveryofOnlineRedoLog:Thread1Group3Seq18966Readingmem0
Mem#0:/storage/app/oracle/oradata/sjzk/redo03.log
RecoveryofOnlineRedoLog:Thread1Group1Seq18967Readingmem0
Mem#0:/storage/app/oracle/oradata/sjzk/redo01.log
RecoveryofOnlineRedoLog:Thread1Group2Seq18968Readingmem0
Mem#0:/storage/app/oracle/oradata/sjzk/redo02.log
RecoveryofOnlineRedoLog:Thread1Group4Seq18969Readingmem0
Mem#0:/storage/app/oracle/oradata/sjzk/redo04.log
Completedredoapplicationof543.73MB
WedSep2716:45:152017
Errorsinfile/storage/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/sjzk/sjzk/trace/sjzk_m000_4200.trc:
ORA-01155:thedatabaseisbeingopened,closed,mountedordismounted
WedSep2717:00:172017
Errorsinfile/storage/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/sjzk/sjzk/trace/sjzk_m000_4362.trc:
ORA-01155:thedatabaseisbeingopened,closed,mountedordismounted
```

sjzk_m000_4200.trc:

```
Trace file /storage/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/sjzk/sjzk/trace/sjzk_m000_4362.trc
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORACLE_HOME = /storage/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
System name:    Linux
Node name:  qyws-6-43
Release:    3.0.13-0.27-default
Version:    #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012 (d73692b)
Machine:    x86_64
VM name:    VMWare Version: 6
Instance name: sjzk
Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1
Oracle process number: 28
Unix process pid: 4362, image: oracle@qyws-6-43 (M000)


*** 2017-09-27 17:00:17.494
*** SESSION ID:(1141.3) 2017-09-27 17:00:17.494
*** CLIENT ID:() 2017-09-27 17:00:17.494
*** SERVICE NAME:() 2017-09-27 17:00:17.494
*** MODULE NAME:(MMON_SLAVE) 2017-09-27 17:00:17.494
*** ACTION NAME:(Monitor FRA Space) 2017-09-27 17:00:17.494

ORA-01155: the database is being opened, closed, mounted or dismounted
```

Is this problem relate to disk?

Comment: It means that a huge transaction was taking place at the time of your shutdown immediate, by doing a shutdown abort you just postponed the rollback at the time of your startup explaining why the startup took so long.

Comment: the  doc is usefu, for the case: https://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2011/07/the-reasons-why-i-always-avoid-to-shutdown-abort.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a shutdown abort database will do crash recovery before opening database. time relates 
  1.volume of blocks need recovery and because of that oracle will roll forward 
    redo to recover corrupted blocks.
  2.Performance of Disk

For first one you can decrease it by setting **fast_start_mttr_target** parameter or you can set redo logfile size to a correct value over your experience of system.
For Second one you should use disks with better performance.